# Oracle Analytic Function.. OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, cumulative-sum

Trying to calculate Total Sales like below with the following query, But getting not a group by error.

```
select country,month,sales,sum(sales) over (partition by country order by month) 
from check2
group by country,month,sales
```

Data

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: Hello to find total sales just use
SUM(SALES)OVER( PARTITION BY COUNTRY) AS total_sales

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OVER..PARTITION BY, then you don't need the GROUP BY.

Just this should be sufficient

```
select country,month,sales,sum(sales) over (partition by country order by month) 
from check2
```

[See example here on LiveSL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GCSDNY72CZOZ3DWO5F64WMY8V.html)

Comment: yeah i didn't go into the SQL, only addressed the OP's error message.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `GROUP BY` and, if you want the total for the entire partition then, don't use `ORDER BY` in the analytic function:

```sql
select country,
       month,
       sales,
       sum(sales) over (partition by country) As total_sales
from   check2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE check2(country, month, sales) AS
SELECT 'US',     202204, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'US',     202205, 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'US',     202206, 5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Canada', 202204, 8000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Canada', 202205, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Canada', 202206, 1000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COUNTRY | MONTH | SALES | TOTAL_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | 202205 | 2000 | 11000 |
| Canada | 202204 | 8000 | 11000 |
| Canada | 202206 | 1000 | 11000 |
| US | 202205 | 3000 | 10000 |
| US | 202204 | 2000 | 10000 |
| US | 202206 | 5000 | 10000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xh_zJJLC)